# Linq most efficient top results

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm wondered I have a table with  IDs and a version and a remove field. I d like to return the the top 20 records grouped by ID and for ech ID take only the highest version unless remove is set then ignore removed records.
Then return a descending record set.

There are a few ways todo it with Linq but I wonder is there a most efficient way, are there patterns to avoid?.

```cs
...
    .OrderByDescending(x=>x.id)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.id)
    .SelectMany(y=>y.Where(x=>x.Version == y.Max(y=>y.Version)))
    .Where(x=>x.Remove=false)
    .Take(20)
```

Comment: Put classes and which queries you have tried. I know one effective way - SQL, but there is LINQ workarounds.

Comment: added code, its working, just wonder if it is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

One of then possible workarounds when using EF Core. I'm calling it workaround because with SQL and Window functions we can create more effective query.

```cs
var itemsQuery = ctx.SomeTable
    .Where(x => x.Remove = false);
    
var query =
    from d in itemsQuery.Select(d => new { d.id }).Distinct()
    from x in itemsQuery.Where(x => d.Id == x.Id)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
        .Take(1)
    select x;

query = query.Take(20);
```

Similar queries when using EF Core 6:

```cs
var query = ctx.SomeTable
    .Where(x => x.Remove = false)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Take(20)
    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).Take(1));
```

```cs
var query = ctx.SomeTable
    .Where(x => x.Remove = false)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).First());
    .Take(20);
```

Comment: I actually was kinda more interested in the pattern, here they produce the same, is there something that is better then other?, ea remove first or is it al bit the same, is there a good practice?

Comment: Profile generated queries. Analyze execution plan. This is the best practice.